# how to read a file in bash and create directories

Tags: bash

I have a `txt` file of the form:

```
Billy-1b
Jim-1b
Kelly-1b
```

The `txt` file is called `names.dat` and is made up of 160 rows. I want to read the file and create a directory of each entry. Following the above example, I should have in my working directory 3 directories: `Billy-1b` `Jim-1b` and `Kelly-1b`. I am new to bash scripting. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `xargs` with `mkdir` like this:

```
xargs mkdir -p < names.dat
```

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over lines with `read` :

```
while read line; do 
  mkdir "$line"
done < names.dat
```

You'll have the same result with :

```
< names.dat xargs -L 1 mkdir
```